# How to use two versions of spark shell?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, version

I have **Spark 1.6.2** and **Spark 2.0** installed on my hortonworks cluster.

Both these versions are installed on a node in the Hadoop Cluster of 5 nodes.

Each time I start the `spark-shell` I get:

```
$ spark-shell
Multiple versions of Spark are installed but SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is not set
Spark1 will be picked by default
```

When I check the version I get:

```
scala> sc.version
res0: String = 1.6.2
```

How can I start the other version(spark-shell of Spark2.0)?

Comment: Reference for answer: [Choose Spark Version](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_spark-component-guide/content/spark-choose-version.html)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2
```

You just need to give the major version 2 or 1.

```
$ export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2
$ spark-submit --version
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is set to 2, using Spark2
Welcome to
   ____              __
  / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
 _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
/___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.0.0.2.5.0.0-1245
```

Comment: This is same as the previous answer.

Comment: Its mentioned  2.0.0 in the other answer  you just need to set the major version

$ export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2
$ spark-submit --version
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is set to 2, using Spark2

Answer (score 3):

Working this approach:

```
spark-shell
```

loads Spark 1.6

whilst typing

```
spark2-shell
```

loads Spark 2.0

Answer (score 1):

```
$ SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 spark-shell
```

Answer (score 1):

use spark2-submit, pyspark2 or spark2-shell

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows 8 or 10 change the environment variables for spark_home for spark2 version or spark3 version whichever you want to use and change the path variable too. and close terminal and restart it

and launch the sparkshell you will be able to see your default version